# drop down list in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hey friends I am using drop down list in my mvc 3 project. Here the user choose one of the options and save it. And when he/she revisit the page than i have to make the initially saved  value as selected value. Actually i am doing this with custom html helper as per need. But i am getting problem on it. I am doing this as:

```
else if (question_type == 7)
        {
            EAI.DAL.EaiEntities entities = new DAL.EaiEntities();
            QuestionnaireRepository repository = new QuestionnaireRepository(entities);
            SelectList typesList = repository.PopDdlList(qid);                 


            output.Append(helper.Label(questiontext));
            if (answer == "")
            {
                output.Append(helper.DropDownList("ddl" + question_id, typesList, "-- select type----));

            }
            else
            {
                output.Append(helper.DropDownList("ddl" + question_id, typesList, answer));

            }


            return helper.Raw(output.ToString());
        }
```

Actually above code renders the selected value from database but it actually replacing the "-- select type ---" . So, After saving once if i visit the same page and save the page than i can get empty value in Formcollection.

So, please suggest the appropriate  way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a few properties in my model:

```
int SelectedCategory { get; set; }

IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; private set; }
```

and then load the data in my model constructor:

```
ProductService productService = new ProductService();

this.Categories =
    productService.GetCategories()
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Name, Id = c.Id.ToString() });

this.Categories.InsertAt(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "--- Please Select ---", value = "" });
```

then in my Razor markup do something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)
```

This should auto wire up in the standard MVC way.  Hope this helps.